# Any way to use a canvas element's background for pixel manipulation?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a color picker. I have a canvas element with a radial-gradient background. However, i am having trouble figuring out how i can get the pixel data from this canvas so that i can assign it to other variables.

the code below is what i have so far. My focus right now is only on the canvas element named "color-picker."

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="picker-content-holder">

            <div class="color-picker-container">
                <div id="hovered-color" style="background: rgba(red, green, blue);">rgba</div>
                <canvas id="color-picker" class="color-picker">
                    <div class="color-selector"></div>
                </canvas>
            </div>
            
            <div class="color-lightness-container">
                <div class="lightness-title">Lightness</div>
                <canvas id="color-lightness" class="color-lightness">
                    <div class="lightness-selector"></div>
                </canvas>
            </div>
            <div class="colorValueBoxes">
                <div class="rgb"></div>
                <div class="hsl"></div>
                <div class="hex"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

```
html * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: auto;
}

div {
    display: block;
}

/* Containers Styling */

.picker-content-holder {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    max-width: 600px;
}

.color-picker-container {
    padding: 40px;
    position: relative;
    aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}

.color-lightness-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}

/* Color Lightness Styling */

.color-lightness {
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(.25turn, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(255, 255, 255));
}

.lightness-selector {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 98.2%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px .5px rgb(70, 70, 70), 0 0 5px 1px rgb(70, 70, 70);
}

/* Color Picker Styling */

.color-picker {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px 2px black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0,red,rgba(242,13,13,.8) 10%,rgba(230,26,26,.6) 20%,rgba(204,51,51,.4) 30%,rgba(166,89,89,.2) 40%,hsla(0,0%,50%,0) 50%),radial-gradient(circle at 85.35533905932738% 14.644660940672622%,#ffbf00,rgba(242,185,13,.8) 10%,rgba(230,179,26,.6) 20%,rgba(204,166,51,.4) 30%,rgba(166,147,89,.2) 40%,hsla(0,0%,50%,0) 50%),radial-gradient(circle at 100% 50%,#80ff00,rgba(128,242,13,.8) 10%,rgba(128,230,26,.6) 20%,rgba(128,204,51,.4) 30%,rgba(128,166,89,.2) 40%,hsla(0,0%,50%,0) 50%),radial-gradient(circle at 85.35533905932738% 85.35533905932738%,#00ff40,rgba(13,242,70,.8) 10%,rgba(26,230,77,.6) 20%,rgba(51,204,89,.4) 30%,rgba(89,166,108,.2) 40%,hsla(0,0%,50%,0) 50%),radial-gradient(circle at 50.00000000000001% 100%,#0ff,rgba(13,242,242,.8) 10%,rgba(26,230,230,.6) 20%,rgba(51,204,204,.4) 30%,rgba(89,166,166,.2) 40%,hsla(0,0%,50%,0) 50%),radial-gradient(circle at 14.64466094067263% 85.35533905932738%,#0040ff,rgba(13,70,242,.8) 10%,rgba(26,77,230,.6) 20%,rgba(51,89,204,.4) 30%,rgba(89,108,166,.2) 40%,hsla(0,0%,50%,0) 50%),radial-gradient(circle at 0 50.00000000000001%,#7f00ff,rgba(128,13,242,.8) 10%,rgba(128,26,230,.6) 20%,rgba(128,51,204,.4) 30%,rgba(128,89,166,.2) 40%,hsla(0,0%,50%,0) 50%),radial-gradient(circle at 14.644660940672615% 14.64466094067263%,#ff00bf,rgba(242,13,185,.8) 10%,rgba(230,26,179,.6) 20%,rgba(204,51,166,.4) 30%,rgba(166,89,147,.2) 40%,hsla(0,0%,50%,0) 50%);
}

.color-selector {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px .5px rgb(70, 70, 70), 0 0 5px 1px rgb(70, 70, 70);
}
```

```
const canvas = document.querySelector(".color-picker").style.background;

const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.addEventListener("load", () => {
  ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
});
const hoveredColor = document.getElementById("hovered-color");
const selectedColor = document.getElementById("selected-color");

function pick(event, destination) {
  const bounding = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = event.clientX - bounding.left;
  const y = event.clientY - bounding.top;
  const pixel = ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1);
  const data = pixel.data;

  const rgba = `rgba(${data[0]}, ${data[1]}, ${data[2]}, ${data[3] / 255})`;
  destination.style.background = rgba;
  destination.textContent = rgba;

  return rgba;
}

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => pick(event, hoveredColor));
canvas.addEventListener("click", (event) => pick(event, selectedColor));
```

Comment: You'd have to reproduce that gradient using the Canvas2D API so that it's drawn on the canvas buffer. Have a look at the `ctx.createRadialGradient()` method, you'll have to define and `fill()` one per `radial-gradient()` function in your CSS rule.

Comment: well, i know how to create the gradients but how do i fill them all together in one canvas?

Comment: i did it. but the result wasnt 100% what i was expecting https://proamateurr.github.io/color-picker-project/